# Prove that G is a group under matrix multiplication.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, proof-writing

Let G be the set of all $2x2$ invertible matrices whose columns add up to 1. So, G is the set of all matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&c\\b&d\end{bmatrix}$ such that $a+b=1$ and $c+d=1$. Prove that G is a group under matrix multiplication.

So I know I have to prove closeness, associativity (which I've done), identity element, and being invertible everywhere, which I'm not sure how to use another matrix B to do so.

Comment: Well, not just $a+b=1$ and $c+d=1$. Also $ad-bc\neq0$, since you need invertible.

Comment: @AloneAndConfused So can the second matrix B just be the identity matrix of a 2x2 matrix? And then just multiply A and B to get closure?

Comment: No,  another matrix of the same form: $$A \, =\, \begin{pmatrix} a & 1-a \\ b & 1-b \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B \, =\, \begin{pmatrix} a' & 1-a' \\ b' & 1-b' \end{pmatrix}. $$ Note what I wrote in my first comment was total rubbish (and hence deleted!) : if $a+b=1$ then $b=1-a$

Comment: @AloneAndConfused $a'$? Doesn't that mean the derivative?

Comment: @AloneAndConfused So is $c=b$? Because if $b=1-a$ then shouldn't that equation go where $b$ is in the matrix and not in the place of $c$?

Comment: Sorry no, should have explained: $a$ and $b$ can be any real number, so $a'$ and $b'$ are just two other real numbers, possibly different from $a$ and $b$. I could have called them something else instead. As for should it be $b$ or $c$, I just relabelled them, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: So I assume $a$ and $b$ are real numbers (not integers, complex numbers or...)? By symmetry it will give an essentially equivalent result, but didn't you sum the rows to 1, not the columns? Shouldn't it be $A= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 1-a & 1-b \end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set of $2\times 2$ matrices defined by:

$$S \, = \, \left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d\end{pmatrix} \; : \; a+b=1, \, c+d=1, \, ad\neq bc\right\}.$$

Then $A\in S$ is of the form

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & c\\ 1-a & 1-c \end{pmatrix}$$

where $a, c\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\neq c$. Now take two matrices in $A$:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ 1-a & 1-c \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} a' & c' \\ 1-a' & 1-c' \end{pmatrix}. $$

with $a, c, a', c' \in\mathbb{R}$ with $a\neq c,  \, a'\neq c'$. 
For closure, we require $AB\in S$:

$$AB = \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ 1-a & 1-a \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a' & c' \\ 1-a' & 1-c' \end{pmatrix} \, =\, \begin{pmatrix} aa' +(1-a')c & ac' +(1-c')c \\ (1-a)a' + (1 - c) (1 - a') & (1-a)c' + (1 - c)(1-c') \end{pmatrix}  $$

which after simplifying gives

$$AB = \begin{pmatrix} aa' +(1-a')c & ac' +(1-c')c  \\ 1-[aa'+(1-a')c] & 1 - [ac' +(1-c')c]  \end{pmatrix}  $$

which is of the same form (elements in first column add to 1, as do the elements in the second column; elements in first row can't be equal since $a\neq c$) and $AB\in S$. Hence $S$ is closed under matrix multiplication. That should get you started.

Comment: Looks good, but again you've shown it for rows not columns or am I just completely confused? Just change it to $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} \; : \; a+c=1, \, b+d=1, \, ad\neq bc\right\}$ and massage a bit and it's done.

Comment: But I need the columns to equal 1, not the rows.

Comment: But the OP question states for $a+b=1$ and $c+d=1$ i.e. the rows being equal not the columns

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I wrote the problem wrong. I corrected the matrix.

Comment: Ah okay. I will enter this answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, although $b$ and $c$ should be switched to match the original matrix in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The "easier" way of doing this is to note the condition on $A$ is equivalent to requiring $A$ to be invertible and satisfy:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}A = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then if $A,B$ satisfy this constraint, show $AB$ satisfies this constraint and that $A^{-1}$ satisfies this constraint.

For example, if $A$ is invertible, and $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}A = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}$ then $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}A^{-1} = \left(\begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}A\right)A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix} I = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\end{pmatrix}$$ So $A^{-1}$ is in our set.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more illuminating (possibly also easier) to proceed as follows.

Let $X$ be the $1\times2$ matrix $X=(1,1)$, a vector if you prefer.
We observe that
$$
G=\{A\in M_{2\times2}(\Bbb{R})\mid \det A\neq0, XA=X\}.
$$
It is then straightforward to prove the following facts, using only what you know about matrix multiplication.

1. If $XA=X$ and $XB=X$ for some $2\times2$ matrices $A$ and $B$ then
   also $X(AB)=X$
2. If $XA=X$ then also $X=XA^{-1}$.

These facts immediately imply that $G$ is a subgroup of the group of invertible $2\times2$-matrices.

---

In a later course you may learn about group actions and stabilizers. Then you can reinterpret this as stating that $G$ is the stabilizer of the vector $X$, when the group of invertible matrices acts on the (row) vectors by matrix muliplication.