# Show that the set $E$ with the multiplication of matrices is a group

Tags: matrices, group-theory

> We consider the set E of square matrices of the form
>
> $$M= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> With $a, b, c ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $ac-b^2=1.$ Show that the set $E$ with the multiplication of matrices is a group.

Comment: I think your $d$ is supposed to be $b$.

Comment: I have updated the matrix

Comment: I tried to edit your post - did I edit it correctly?

Comment: Yes you did it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ac-b^{2}$ is nothing  but $\det(M)$, the determinant of $M$. Use the following facts:

$\det(MN)=\det(M)\det(N)$

$\det(M) \neq 0$ implies $M$ is non-sngular and $\det(M^{-1})=\frac 1 {\det(M)}$

The identity matrix has determinant $1$.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a group under usual matrix multiplication, as the given set is not closed under matrix multiplication. Consider, for example,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 31 & 19 \\ 13 & 8 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: +1. I assume it is a typo, must be addition.

Comment: @farruhota I don't think so; addition will certainly not preserve the determinant condition. I think it was just a lazily-posed question by the instructor.

Comment: Right, I meant it is closed under addition. For the problem to be good-posed, it needs to be finetuned. For example, as given in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167806/prove-that-g-is-a-group-under-matrix-multiplication?rq=1).